# Yii dataprovider of related model for gridview

Tags: gridview, yii

I've User and Company model. They are related to each other.

User's model:

```
'company_r'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Company','user_id'),
```

I want to print specified user's companies in gridview using relation as an example in below:

```
1 | company1
2 | company2
3 | company3
```

I know it's possible using this method:

```
Company::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$user_id));
```

But I'm interested in to do this using this method:

```
$model=User::model()->findByPk($user_id);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
//'dataProvider'=>$model->company_r->search(),
....
```

How can I get related model dataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'title',          
        'category',
        'content:html',   
        array(            
            'header'=>'Company Name',
            'value'=>'$data->company_r->name',
        ),




    ),
));
```

Here company_r is the relation name between user and company. Get the users like

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User',array(
'criteria'=>array()
));
```